# Sysdate: guardar fecha

Tags: oracle, plsql

tengo problemas con el sysdate quiero que me guarde esto la fecha y hora asi
01-09-2020 11:56
mi insert es:

```
insert into fecha ( F_ALTA) values (to_date(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Salida:

```
01/09/0020
```

Probé también con un `to_char` pero no me deja hacer el insert.

No se como puedo insertar la fecha de hoy con la hora en el formato que quiero.
Gracias ded antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es el campo `F_ALTA`?

Comment: @jachguate es un DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle tiene [tipos de datos específicos](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) para almacenar fechas y horas, hablamos de `date` y `timestamp`.

Estos tipos de datos no almacenan la información en ninguna representación visual específica, sino en un tipo binario especializado, lo cual permite aritmética de fechas, ordenamientos y comparaciones de manera óptima.

La función `sysdate` retorna el tipo de dato `date`, por lo cual, para hacer un `insert`/`update`, no tienes que hacer ninguna conversión, simplemente utiliza la función en donde corresponde:

```
insert into fecha(f_alta) values (sysdate);
```

Esto almacenará la fecha y hora del servidor, con precisión hasta segundos (sin fracciones de segundo).

Generalmente, cómo este dato se represente finalmente a un usuario es un tema que se resuelve en la capa de presentación de datos, por ejemplo, el lenguaje de programación que utilizas para construir la interfaz de usuario, y no a nivel de base de datos.

Si por alguna razón quieres *ver* este dato con algún formato particular, digamos en SQL*Plus, tienes las siguientes opciones, que aplican a la hora de recuperar el dato, no a la hora de almacenarlo.

- Ajustar, a nivel de sesión el parámetro `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` al formato en que quieres ver las fechas/horas. Esto generalmente afectará la forma en que serán representadas todas las fechas/horas dentro de la sesión:

  ```
    alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
  ```

  Luego de esto, al lanzar tu consulta:

  ```
    select * from fecha;
  ```

  La fecha estará representada en el formato indicado.

  Debes tener en cuenta que este cambio también afectará la manera en que, durante la sesión, se interpretan cadenas de caracteres que representan fechas y horas.
- Pudes cambiar el valor de `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` a nivel de instancia de oracle (con el parámetro de inicialización del mismo nombre). Esto hará que todas las sesiones tengan por defecto el valor que tu pongas, y siempre a nivel de cada sesión se puede cambiar según convenga.
- En una sentencia específica, independientemente del valor de `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, puedes utiliza la función `TO_CHAR()`, lo que hará que el motor devuelva una cadena de caracteres ya con la representación que quieres ver. **OJO**, que esto es sub-optimo si estas lanzando la consulta desde un lenguaje de programación, como he dicho al inicio, es mejor trabajar con los valores de tipo `date`, que con cadenas.

  ```
    select to_char(f_alta, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from fecha;
  ```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, Sara, te recomiendo re-leer la respuesta, pues luego de publicarla hice algunos ajustes para expresar mejor la idea. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate, muy buena respuesta; por alguna razón desconocida este tema de las fechas es recurrente la confusión entre el formato visual y el almacenamiento interno